# RTX 2080 Ti cuda-memcheck hit error at the beginning of creating Cublas context

Tags: cuda, gpu, cublas

I run the same program on both GTX 1080 Ti and RTX 2080 Ti. I found that when I try to use Cuda-memcheck tool to check my program, I always got the following errors based on the device RTX 2080 Ti.

```
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Program hit cudaErrorInvalidValue (error 11) due to "invalid argument" on CUDA API call to cudaFuncSetAttribute. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 [0x359363]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so.10.0 [0x79a03c]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so.10.0 [0x72c2ab]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so.10.0 [0x72c610]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so.10.0 (cublasCreate_v2 + 0x1ce7) [0x14b337]
=========     Host Frame:./GPU_LMM (main + 0x43) [0xb633]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xe7) [0x21b97]
=========     Host Frame:./GPU_LMM (_start + 0x2a) [0xb77a]
=========
========= Program hit cudaErrorInvalidValue (error 11) due to "invalid argument" on CUDA API call to cudaGetLastError. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 [0x359363]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so.10.0 [0x79deb3]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so.10.0 [0x72c2b8]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so.10.0 [0x72c610]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so.10.0 (cublasCreate_v2 + 0x1ce7) [0x14b337]
```

I make sure that what I do at this point is only to create a Cublas context and do nothing. I am not sure what the problem is. Is it caused by the version mismatching between CUDA 10.0 and RTX 2080 Ti?

The information about my server is as the following.
NVIDIA-SMI 410.93       Driver Version: 410.93       CUDA Version: 10.0

Comment: That almost certainly men's that the cublas version you are using doesn't have support for that card

Comment: @talonmies The information about my server is as the following. NVIDIA-SMI 410.93 Driver Version: 410.93 CUDA Version: 10.0.

Comment: do you use CuBlas 10? It is required for RTX cards

Comment: @DanielBauer Could you please tell me how I can check the CuBlas version? I just install the newest version of CUDA

Comment: I don't use the CUDA libraries, so I don't know exactly. But it is definitly included in CUDA 10 install. Maybe you have an older version still installed and are linking to it...

Comment: This is a known issue on CUDA 10 on Turing devices, and is expected to be fixed in the next public CUDA release.  It accurately reflects CUBLAS behavior which will be fixed.  The problem/behavior is benign, so the report can be considered spurious in a larger context.  I don't have further information at this time and won't be able to respond to requests for further information or expected CUDA release dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is that the Cublas library is not compatible with the Cuda 10 version and RTX gpu card.

Comment: CUDA 10 CUBLAS is compatible with RTX GPUs.  There is a rather minor issue in that if you run it under `cuda-memcheck`, a benign error will be flagged.  The occurrence of this error doesn't mean that the behavior or the results are suspect.

Answer (score 2):

The RTX2080 Ti should be supported in the latest CUDA Version 10.0.130
Make sure your Driver is up to date too.

On Linux, that is Driver version >= 410.48 and on Windows >= 411.31

CuBlas got Turing support in Version 10, too.

Comment: nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130